# Difference Pivot_table Pandas and excel

Tags: excel, pandas, pivot

When I create a pivot table from data in Pandas (python), I get an other result than when I create it with Excel. I think this is due to the fact of characters. Someone knows the difference between the pivot table in Pandas and Excel?

I've made this example. I have the excel file 'funds_steven' with following data in 1 column. (column name = Steven_Funds)

```
Steven_Funds
0   100
1   -58
2   89
3   24
4   -89
5   76
6   -4
7   -180
8   767
9   0
10  0
11  56
12  32
13  0
14  0
15  12
```

How can I read this in and calculate the sum of the values?

Comment: Always helps if you could show expected result and pandas result to debug.

Comment: Taking the sum of all these values is not really a pivot table. For the sum you can just use the `sum()` method